# How to Use Action Filter in Winform App Console app OR any Class Method in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, c#-4.0

I Want To Log When any method execution started and when that method execution is completed.
so In MVC, I can use Action Filter but I Want the same thing to implement in Console App as well as the Winform app, I have checked there is Postsharp like the NuGet package is available but I don't want to use that.

so is there any other way to implement this kind of thing?

Comment: The problem is, you want to add some automatically added "debug" information in your program. I've had this wish also, but ended up with a performance profiler. Because you don't want to change your functionality of the program. If you need it inside your program, because it is required functionality, you should add it to the method or wrap the methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create a class and extend it from ActionFilterAttribute. now it has four methods that are shown below. you can skip or implement any of these methods according to your requirment

> OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext)    Called after the action
> method executes.
>
> OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext)  Called before the action
> method executes.
>
> OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext)    Called after the action
> result executes.
>
> OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext)  Called  before the action
> result executes.

```
   public class GenerateLogsAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
            {
    //excuted after actionmethod returns
                public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
                {
                   //this code will execute when actionmethod has returned
                }
      public override void OnActionExecuting(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
                {
                   //this code will start running before action methods start execute
                }
            }
```

Now you have decorate your actionmethod with attribute of you custom actionfilter (exclude Attribute word) here in our case it will be

```
  [GenerateLogs]
  public IActionResult YourMethod(){//your code}
```

and in console App you can create three methods

1. you want to run before your method (BeforeExecute)
2. you want to run after your method (AfterExecute)
3. containing call to methods in this order beforeexecute() yourmethod() afterexecute()

   ```
    public string AnotherFunction()
    {
    BeforeExecuting(); //code that you want to run before method start
    YourMethod(); // your actual code
    AfterExecuting(); // code that you want to run after methods has 
    returned
    }
   ```

Comment: but i have a traditional winform app and console app where is class method not controller action than is this work ?

Comment: i have implemented in class method in MVC app but it's not working

Comment: @kailash then this method would not work. an other approach is that you create three extra methods in class or may be in a baseclass and then call these methods before and after your method call

public string AnaotherFunction()
{
BeforeExecuting();
youFunction();
Afterexecuting();
}

Comment: @kailash I have also updated answer to put my suggestion for console app in answer